# Storing trillions of document similarities

Tags: sql, performance, csv, bigdata

I wrote a program to compute similarities among a set of 2 million documents. The program works, but I'm having trouble storing the results. I won't need to access the results often, but will occasionally need to query them and pull out subsets for analysis. The output basically looks like this:

```
1,2,0.35
1,3,0.42
1,4,0.99
1,5,0.04
1,6,0.45
1,7,0.38
1,8,0.22
1,9,0.76
.
.
.
```

Columns 1 and 2 are document ids, and column 3 is the similarity score. Since the similarity scores are symmetric I don't need to compute them all, but that still leaves me with 2000000*(2000000-1)/2 ≈ 2,000,000,000,000 lines of records.

A text file with 1 million lines of records is already 9MB. Extrapolating, that means I'd need  17 TB to store the results like this (in flat text files).

Are there more efficient ways to store these sorts of data? I could have one row for each document and get rid of the repeated document ids in the first column. But that'd only go so far. What about file formats, or special database systems? This must be a common problem in "big data"; I've seen papers/blogs reporting similar analyses, but none discuss practical dimensions like storage.

Comment: Are you interested in documents that are more similar to others?  Could you get get the same results by only saving records that have a similarity score above 0.50 (or something like that)?  In other words, is there another way to look at the problem?

Comment: I've tried a few tricks like that to pare the list down and it helps a little. But I'm still interested in the more general problem of how you store a huge amount of data like this, especially when it's got a very simple structure.

Comment: Compression may help some with respect to the space needed. Depends on the database you're using. This goes over some of the basic syntax for Oracle http://dbaora.com/table-compression-in-oracle-11g/ Because you're storing the result of the comparison in the database and not using the database in any way for the comparisons, I don't really see any way around storing all of it. Compression will at least reduce the space consumed by the data.

Comment: i think you could use unsigned short (2B) instead of double (8B) for similarity part, as it's between 0.0 and 1.0 and I think you use 0.01 precision, it's right to define them between 0 and 100.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to store this much information? In practical terms, can you even compare all these documents before the Sun dies (or the Cubs win the World Series)? Is it useful information to store, rather than comparing two documents of interest on-the-fly?  Sometimes people go off on these projects and get all wrapped up in the technical details, without looking at the Big Picture. Maybe you could store one line of "summary" for each file, and use that to decide which ones to do a detailed comparison on.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I don't have any practical experience with this, but it's a fun exercise and after some thinking this is what I came up with:

Since you have 2.000.000 documents you're kind of stuck with an integer for the document id's; that makes 4 bytes + 4 bytes; the comparison seems to be between 0.00 and 1.00, I guess a byte would do by encoding the 0.00-1.00 as 0..100.

So your table would be : id1, id2, relationship_value

That brings it to exactly 9 bytes per record. Thus (without any overhead) ((2 * 10^6)^2)*9/2bytes are needed, that's about 17Tb.

Off course that's if you have just a basic table. Since you don't plan on querying it very often I guess performance isn't that much of an issue. So you could go 'creative' by storing the values 'horizontally'. 
Simplifying things, you would store the values in a 2 million by 2 million square and each 'intersection' would be a byte representing the relationship between their coordinates. This would "only" require about 3.6Tb, but it would be a pain to maintain, and it also doesn't make use of the fact that the relations are symmetrical.

So I'd suggest to use a hybrid approach, a table with 2 columns. First column would hold the 'left' document-id (4 bytes), 2nd column would hold a string of all values of documents starting with an id above the id in the first column using a varbinary. Since a varbinary only takes the space that it needs, this helps us win back some space offered by the symmetry of the relationship.

In other words,

- record 1 would have a string of (2.000.000-1) bytes as value for the 2nd column
- record 2 would have a string of (2.000.000-2) bytes as value for the 2nd column
- record 3 would have a string of (2.000.000-3) bytes as value for the 2nd column
- etc

That way you should be able to get away with something like 2Tb (inc overhead) to store the information. Add compression to it and I'm pretty sure you can store it on a modern disk.

Off course the system is far from optimal. In fact, querying the information will require some patience as you can't approach things set-based and you'll pretty much have to scan things byte by byte. A nice 'benefit' of this approach would be that you can easily add new documents by adding a new byte to the string of EACH record + 1 extra record in the end. Operations like that will be costly though as it will result in page-splits; but at least it will be possible without having to completely rewrite the table. But it will cause quite bit of fragmentation over time and you might want to rebuild the table once in a while to make it more 'aligned' again. Ah.. technicalities.

Selecting and Updating will require some creative use of SubString() operations, but nothing too complex..

PS: Strictly speaking, for 0..100 you only need 7 bytes, so if you really want to squeeze the last bit out of it you could actually store 8 values in 7 bytes and save another ca 300Mb, but it would make things quite a bit more complex... then again, it's not like the data is going to be human-readable anyway =)

PS: this line of thinking is completely geared towards reducing the amount of space needed while remaining practical in terms of updating the data. I'm not saying it's going to be fast; in fact, if you'd go searching for all documents that *have a relation-value of 0.89 or above* the system will have to scan the entire table and even with modern disks that IS going to take a while.

Mind you that all of this is the result of half an hour brainstorming; I'm actually hoping that someone might chime in with a neater approach =)

Comment: Some simple optimizations: if everything is in strict order with no gaps, you could skip the first field and make it part of the file name (e.g., doc_1.txt). The comparison value might be as little as two bytes ('76' instead of '0.76'). Maybe 3 if some are 1.00. You could even store 0..100 in a single unsigned int char. Saving the 2nd document number as a 3 or 4 byte binary could save space. Does this have to be human readable? If not, you might squeeze it down to 4 bytes per record, fixed length records (no \n).

Comment: I came up with a similar matrix approach, row# is document 1 and col# is document 2, 7 bits per entry = roughly 1.75TB. If there are not going to be updates, I'd probably use a flat file approach with a custom extraction/creation routines. I haven't looked at it at all, but came across it thinking about this question, and [HDF](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) could potentially be interesting. Let us know what you decide.

Comment: @PhilPerry: storing the information in 'one file per document could be an option too indeed. That way you use the filesystem to do the 'growing/paging' when adding new information. Keep in mind thou that you will loose the benefit of ACID etc that db's offer; but I guess that if you can write a program to create similarities between 2M documents that coding this shouldn't be too difficult either. Using e.g. NTFS you could even switch on file-compression and never have to worry about it. I'd prefer to store it in an MSSQL db and use SQLCLR to query it, but 'just files' indeed sounds KISS.